# Socket io not working over https, how to solve that?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, socket.io

I run this node script on my server, I can connect via my localhost copy of my webpage. However, I canon't connect from the copy hosted on my server as it's served over HTTPS. I get the error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// ***** .com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://***** :5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Npij0pe'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

socket.io server side code

```
const server = require('http').createServer();
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Sockete birileri bağlandı');

  socket.on('send-message', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    io.emit('messages', data);
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('birileri geldi ve gitti')
  })
});


server.listen(5000);
```

client side:

```
var socket = io('https://*****:5000');
```

php controller:

```
$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://*****:5000'));
        $client->initialize();
        $client->emit('send-message', [
            'sender_id' => $currentUser_company_id,
            'reciver_id' => $user->company_id,
            'messege' => request()->message_text,
            'send_time' => date("H:i")
        ]);
        $client->close();
```

It's working well on localhost, but it's not over https. How can i solve this error ?

Comment: are you using https with working certs setup on port 5000? it doesn't look that way. btw you should use just `io(':5000')` then it will use the origin protocol and host

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i couldn't solve it. Can you please help ? :)

Comment: you need to setup ssl cert, simply changing http to https wont work, also you say it working on localhost? have you setup ssl on localhost on port 5000 with valid certs?